# Tell if object isinstance of PyDatetime or Pydate?

Tags: rust, pyo3

Here's my `main.rs` file:

```
use pyo3::prelude::*;
use pyo3::types::{PyDateTime, PyDate};

fn main() -> () {
    Python::with_gil(|py| {
        let datetime = py.import("datetime").unwrap();
        let my_datetime = datetime.call_method1("datetime", (2022, 3, 28, 0, 0, 0, 0)).unwrap();
        println!("isinstance pydatetime: {:?}", my_datetime.is_instance_of::<PyDateTime>().unwrap());
        println!("isinstance pydate: {:?}", my_datetime.is_instance_of::<PyDate>().unwrap());

        let my_date = datetime.call_method1("date", (2022, 3, 28)).unwrap();
        println!("isinstance pydatetime: {:?}", my_date.is_instance_of::<PyDateTime>().unwrap());
        println!("isinstance pydate: {:?}", my_date.is_instance_of::<PyDate>().unwrap());
    })
}
```

Here's my `Cargo.toml` file:

```ini
[package]
name = "tmp"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
pyo3 = { version = "0.18.0", features = ["auto-initialize"] }
```

If I run the above, I get

```
isinstance pydatetime: true
isinstance pydate: true
isinstance pydatetime: true
isinstance pydate: true
```

I find this a bit odd, because running in Python directly, I get:

```py
In [27]: import datetime as dt

In [28]: isinstance(my_datetime, dt.datetime)
Out[28]: True

In [29]: isinstance(my_datetime, dt.date)
Out[29]: True

In [30]: isinstance(my_date, dt.datetime)
Out[30]: False

In [31]: isinstance(my_date, dt.date)
Out[31]: True
```

So, I would have expected

```
my_date.is_instance_of::<PyDateTime>().unwrap()
```

to also be `false`

Why is that not the case, and how can I distinguish between whether an object is `datetime` or `date` without resorting to more hacky methods like checking `dt.get_type().name()`?

Comment: You might want to report this to pyo3 because there's something really wrong happening: I tried going through [PyTypeInfo](https://pyo3.rs/main/doc/pyo3/type_object/trait.pytypeinfo) and PyO3-level types for initialisation to avoid getting lost with Python-level types, and both `PyDate` and `PyDateTime` are reported as being the type of a `PyDateTime::new` result but neither is reported to be its exact type, and PyDate is even weirder: `PyDateTime::is_exact_type_of(my_date)` returns `true`, but `PyDateTime::is_type_of(my_date)` returns `false`.

Comment: Even getting the Python-level `isinstance` from the builtins, I still get `True` when asking if `my_date` is an instance of `datetime`.

Comment: My pull request has been accepted, so this should be fixed in the next version: https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3/pull/3071

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've submitted a pull request to PyO3 that should fix this: https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3/pull/3071

```diff
diff --git a/src/types/datetime.rs b/src/types/datetime.rs
index 85860728568..2c995356e2c 100644
--- a/src/types/datetime.rs
+++ b/src/types/datetime.rs
@@ -228,7 +228,7 @@ pub struct PyDateTime(PyAny);
 pyobject_native_type!(
     PyDateTime,
     crate::ffi::PyDateTime_DateTime,
-    *ensure_datetime_api(Python::assume_gil_acquired()).DateType,
+    *ensure_datetime_api(Python::assume_gil_acquired()).DateTimeType,
     #module=Some("datetime"),
     #checkfunction=PyDateTime_Check
 );
```